# Is there a way to use two colormaps in a pyplot scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I've got a spatial dataset that I'm plotting with a scatterplot, and I'm wondering if there is a way to use two colormaps for the data depending on a categorical variable? Basically I want to colorize a functional relationship by latitude, but I also want to identify landcover as part of the visualization.

Landcover in my case would be a binary indicator, and the colormap indicates the latitude that a point occurs at. Making this more clear, I have

- A response variable Y
- A predictor variable X
- The latitude where each point (X, Y) occurs at (which is what I want to colorize)
- A binary indicator for landcover that I want to incorporate in the visualization

The code I have now is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# generating sample data as an example
x = np.random.normal(size = 192 * 50)
y = np.random.normal(size = 192 * 50)
lat = np.tile(np.linspace(-90, 90, 192), 50)
landcover = np.random.choice([0, 1], size = 192 * 50, replace = True)

# create a colorbar
cmap = sns.dark_palette("#69d", reverse = True, as_cmap = True)

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 8))
plt.scatter(x, y, c = lat, alpha = 0.2, cmap = cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.solids.set(alpha = 1) # to counter the transparency in the plot
plt.grid(alpha = 0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm not sure how to approach modifying this code to add the landcover information. I envisioned adding another colorbar to the right of the current one and just plotting subsets of the data based on the indicator variable. And I know how to do every step except adding the second colorbar as described. Has anyone ever solved an equivalent problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two different color colormaps in the same imshow matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128166/two-different-color-colormaps-in-the-same-imshow-matplotlib)

Comment: @MykolaZotko, I think it uses an imshow call instead but otherwise works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.
To achieve it, you will use `plt.scatter` twice for each dataset and change the colormap there. With respect to the colorbar, that's trickier.  Use the following code

```
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cm

plt.colorbar(mappable=cm.ScalarMappable(norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1, clip=False),\
            cmap=plt.get_cmap("BrBG")), location='left')
plt.colorbar(mappable=cm.ScalarMappable(norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1, clip=False),\
            cmap=plt.get_cmap("BrBG")), location='right')
```

Don't forget to change cmap to the one yout dataset uses and also change the boundaries if needed. You may also need to refer to your axes but I am not so sure of that. However, this should work

Comment: This was the perfect solution (with changes to the colormaps you'd suggested). I was expecting it to require defining new axes or something to get the way I was looking for.